# Adding down triangle to the top border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a Triangle to top border of active class in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/pw61rm8L/).

[image]

I am using this CSS rules:

```
.xxx a {
    border-top: 3px solid #E1483F;
}
.xxx .active > a:after {
    border-top: 12px solid #E1483F;
}
```

But as you can see I am not getting the Triangle plus the item (CSS) is moving down the previous position. How can I fix this?

Comment: You posted a wrong JSFiddle.

Comment: Hi pianoman99 actually it is not wrong fiddle, y must re-size the result panel to see the navs, thanks

Comment: Can't see any code for creating a triangle in that fiddle. You are just adding a `border-top`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve it like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fn93my3u/)**

```
.navbar-nav > li {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.active:before {
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 12px 0 12px;
    border-color: #E1483F transparent transparent transparent;
}
```